# Why this returns SQL command not properly ended?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why below query returns SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

```
INSERT INTO SYNC_MASTERS_TO_PS(
                           MASTER_CD,
                           LANG_CD,
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           PS_CD
                          )
SELECT 27542003,
       99,
       m_office_types,
       a.ps_cd
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PS_CD
          FROM M_POLICE_STATION
         WHERE STATE_CD = 27)
       AS a
```

Comment: Wrap `m_office_types` with single quote?

Comment: Oracle dose not support 'AS' for table alias

Comment: Thanks Forward and Aleksej. Your comments solved this issue.

Comment: Special thanks to Forward and Aleksej who suggested to remove 'AS' and wrap 'm_office_types' with single quotes, which resolved issue. Now corrected query is: > INSERT INTO SYNC_MASTERS_TO_PS (MASTER_CD,LANG_CD,TABLE_NAME,PS_CD)
> SELECT 27542003,99,'m_office_types',a.ps_cd FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
> PS_CD FROM M_POLICE_STATION WHERE STATE_CD=27 ) a

Comment: You select two columns from a sub-query that returns only one column. Don't forget m_office_types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `m_office_types` is a variable you defined somewhere, you have to remove the `AS` from table alias:

```
INSERT INTO SYNC_MASTERS_TO_PS(
                           MASTER_CD,
                           LANG_CD,
                           TABLE_NAME,
                           PS_CD
                          )
SELECT 27542003,
       99,
       m_office_types,
       a.ps_cd
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PS_CD
          FROM M_POLICE_STATION
         WHERE STATE_CD = 27)
       a
```

Answer (score 0):

Highlighted query(bold) returns only one column and you are extracting multiple columns in the query(italicised) part, you need to add m_office_types output in query(bold).

INSERT INTO SYNC_MASTERS_TO_PS (MASTER_CD,LANG_CD,TABLE_NAME,PS_CD) *SELECT 27542003,99,m_office_types,a.ps_cd* FROM (**SELECT DISTINCT PS_CD FROM M_POLICE_STATION WHERE STATE_CD=27** ) as a

Comment: Maybe m_office_types is a variable. However the 'AS' for table alias is not supported in Oracle